# Mandatory field error on journal entry screen

Tags: acumatica

Made the journal entry description field mandatory with below code:
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Data.EP;

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
using PX.Api;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Objects.Common;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CA;
using PX.Objects.FA;
using PX.Objects.GL.JournalEntryState;
using PX.Objects.GL.JournalEntryState.PartiallyEditable;
using PX.Objects.GL.Overrides.PostGraph;
using PX.Objects.GL.Reclassification.UI;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.GL;

namespace PX.Objects.GL
{

  public class JournalEntry_Extension:PXGraphExtension<JournalEntry>
  {

    #region Event Handlers
    //start my code
    [PXDefault]
    [PXCustomizeBaseAttribute(typeof(PXUIFieldAttribute), "Required", true)]
    //end my code

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible)]
    [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true)]
    protected virtual void Batch_Description_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {

    }





    #endregion

  }


}
```

however, I receive an error message when browsing records as below:
[image]

Error:
Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Description : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Boolean' to type 'System.String'..

Not sure what I'm doing wrong
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the **Required** property to **True** using **PXUIField** Attribute. See sample below (Please notice that there are **NO quotes** on Required Property):

```
public class JournalEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<JournalEntry>
{

    #region Event Handlers
    [PXDefault]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Description", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible, Required = true)]
    [PXDBString(255, IsUnicode = true)]
    protected virtual void Batch_Description_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
    {

    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works except that it applies to all journal entries created from other modules as well (what I need is just graph level or screen level block when a user create a manual journal)

Comment: If you need optional required look at PXUIRequired. Here is an example:  [PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<PaymentMethod.useForAP, Equal<True>,
   And<PaymentMethod.aPCreateBatchPayment, Equal<True>>>))]

Comment: my original code was based on Acumatica help file https://help.acumatica.com/(W(9))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=97f5b92f-906a-4edd-ae38-f5605e83d845   and used the below format as defined under graph level [PXDefault]
[PXCustomizeBaseAttribute(typeof(PXUIFieldAttribute), "Required", true)]
protected void DACName_FieldPropertyName_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{
} not sure why this cannot be used to make a field mandatory only on one screen. its good to know the conditional required option though thanks Brendan